# Related to class of "ctime" library

Tags: c++

```
tm time_info= tm();
```

Here in this c++ statement `time_info` is object of `tm` class, `tm()` also denotes the object of `tm()` class.

The constructor will be called for both of them, then whats the need to `time_info=tm()`?

Comment: Are you asking why there needs to be an assignment? i.e. Why couldnt it be written as `tm time_info;`?

Comment: or `tm time_info{}` if you really want to make it explicit that it's being called with no parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
tm time_info= tm();
```

`tm` is the struct name, i.e. the *type* of the single object named `time_info` that you are *defining* in this line. **`tm()` is a call to the constructor of class `tm`** for the object named `time_info` -- it is there to make sure the object is initialized appropriately.

> ... tm() also denotes the object of tm() class.

`tm()` **does not denote any object**. `tm()` **is not a class**.

> The constructor will be called for both of them, ...

No, **the constructor will be called once**, and will initialize the object `time_info`. This is how the C++ syntax is defined: there is no actuall assignment/copying going on in this line (it's a language feature called *copy elision*), and in fact, as said, there aren't two instances to begin with, only one.

Answer (score 0):

These two statements are equivalent:

```
tm time_info;
tm time_info = tm ();
```

In both cases, an object of type `tm` is constructed in `time_info` (and in the second case, [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) avoids the need to copy the newly constructed object).

Don't do this though:

```
tm time_info ();
```

as it will be taken as a function declaration, see:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

See also live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/9XBJMSnYQuSmlmd7